# unable to initialize the AmazonDynamoDBClient class

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am unable to initialize the AmazonDynamoDBClient class and I'm not sure why. It was working fine before but lately I've been getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ThrottleException
at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics$MetricRegistry.<init>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:868)
at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:342)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<clinit>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:244)
```

The code where I'm trying to initialize:

```
private static final String ACCESS_KEY = <access_key_here>;
private static final String SECRET_KEY = <secret_key_here>;
private static final AmazonDynamoDBClient DYNAMO_CLIENT = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY)).withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
```

Comment: Can you put the code of where you are trying to initialize it?

Comment: How are you adding the AWS SDK to your project and what version are you using?